# Children useCallback dependency hell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, usecallback

From what I understand you use useCallback to prevent rerendering so I've been using it in every function and my spider senses are telling me it already sounds bad.

But the story doesn't ends there, since I've been using it everywhere I'm now passing dependencies to all my child components that they shouldn't need to worry about like in the following example :

EDIT // SANDBOX:  https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-noether-0wdnp?file=/src/App.js

Parent component (needs colorButtons and currentColor)

```
const ColorPicker = ({onChange}) => {
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState({r: 255, g:0, b: 0})
    const [colorButtons, setColorButtons] = useState({0: null})

    const handleColorButtons = useCallback((isToggled, id) => {
        /* code that uses colorButtons and currentColor */
    }, [colorButtons, currentColor])

    return <div className="color-picker">
        <RgbColorPicker color={currentColor} onChange={setCurrentColor} />
        <div className="color-buttons">
            {
                Object.entries(colorButtons).map(button => <ColorButton
                    //...
                    currentColor={currentColor}
                    onClick={handleColorButtons}
                    colorButtons={colorButtons}
                />)
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

1st child (needs style and currentColor but gets colorButtons for free from its parent)

```
const ColorButton = ({currentColor, onClick, id, colorButtons}) => {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState({})

    const handleClick = useCallback((isToggled) => {
        /* code that uses setStyle and currentColor */
    }, [style, currentColor, colorButtons])

    return <ToggleButton
        //...
        onClick={handleClick}
        style={style}
        dependency1={style}
        dependency2={currentColor}
        dependency3={colorButtons}
    >
    </ToggleButton>
}
```

2nd child (only needs its own variables but gets the whole package)

```
const ToggleButton = ({children, className, onClick, style, data, id, onRef, ...dependencies}) => {
    const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false)
    const [buttonStyle, setButtonStyle] = useState(style)

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        /* code that uses isToggled, data, id and setButtonStyle */
    }, [isToggled, data, id, ...Object.values(dependencies)])

    return <button 
        className={className || "toggle-button"} 
        onClick={handleClick}
        style={buttonStyle || {}}
        ref={onRef}
    >
        {children}
    </button>
}
```

Am I doing an anti-pattern and if so, what is it and how to fix it ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Could you explain what the idea behind this is? Also, the `colorButtons` variable is unclear both from usage and context... what is its purpose? I would not think about using `useCallback` until I have a performance problem OR some very odd behaviour that I can't solve without using `useCallback`. The addition of complexity should always be balanced against the reduced readability and if it doesn't add anything to the table, it should be avoided.

Comment: @fast-reflexes colorButtons is an object containing the color buttons { [id]: {r,g,b} }, if the button doesn't contain any color at the moment its id will be equal to null instead of {r,g,b}.
So what you're telling me is that's "ok" to do this (not necessarily bad) but if it's not needed for those performance reasons it's useless ?

Comment: Is the number of buttons variable? What's the purpose of the `id`? Yes, if it works well without `useCallback` is would not use it. You want to use `useCallback` either when there is a function that does expensive calculations in a component which has to rerender often, but where the result of the function will be the same across most renderings (e.g. you have performance issues which are unnecessary) OR when the identity of functions are integral and depended upon in some way that makes the component behave bad when a function changes referential identity between renders.

Comment: Could you provide a sandbox? It's hard to give you a meaningful answer and reference your use case when it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I will have a look today and give you some useful feedback :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### React hook `useCallback`

`useCallback` is a hook that can be used in functional React components. A functional component is a function that returns a React component and that runs on every render, which means that everything defined in its body get new referential identities every time. An exception to this can be accomplished with React hooks which may be used inside functional components to interconnect different renders and maintain state. This means that if you save a reference to a regular function defined in a functional component using a ref, and then compare it to the same function in a later render, they will not be the same (the function changes *referential identity* between renderings):

```
// Render 1
...
const fnInBody = () => {}
const fn = useRef(null)
console.log(fn.current === fnInBody) // false since fn.current is null
fn.current = fnInBody
...


// Render 2
...
const fnInBody = () => {}
const fn = useRef(null)
console.log(fn.current === fnInBody) // false due to different identity
fn.current = fnInBody
...
```

As per [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), `useCallback` returns **"a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed"** which is useful **"when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders"**.

To sum up, `useCallback` will return a function that maintains its referential identity (e.g. is memoized) as long as the dependencies don't change. The returned function contains a closure with the used dependencies and must thus be updated once the dependencies change.

This results in this updated version of the previous example

```
// Render 1
...
const fnInBody = useCallback(() => {}, [])
const fn = useRef(null)
console.log(fn.current === fnInBody) // false since fn.current is null
fn.current = fnInBody
...


// Render 2
...
const fnInBody = useCallback(() => {}, [])
const fn = useRef(null)
console.log(fn.current === fnInBody) // true
fn.current = fnInBody
...
```

### Your use case

Keeping the above description in mind, let's have a look at your use of `useCallback`.

#### Case 1: `ColorPicker`

```
const handleColorButtons = useCallback((isToggled, id) => {
    /* code that uses colorButtons and currentColor */
}, [colorButtons, currentColor])
```

This function will get a new identity every time `colorButtons` or `currentColor` changes. `ColorPicker` itself rerenders either when one of these two are set or when its prop `onChange` changes. Both `handleColorButtons` and the children should be updated when `currentColor` or `colorButtons` change. The *only* time the children benefit from the use of `useCallback` is when *only* `onChange` changes. Given that `ColorButton` is a lightweight component, and that `ColorPicker` rerenders mostly due to changes to `currentColor` and `colorButtons`, the use of `useCallback` here seems redundant.

### Case 2: `ColorButton`

```
const handleClick = useCallback((isToggled) => {
    /* code that uses setStyle and currentColor */
}, [style, currentColor, colorButtons])
```

This is a situation similar to the first case. `ColorButton` rerenders when `currentColor`, `onClick`, `id` or `colorButtons` change and the children rerender when `handleClick`, `style`, `colorButtons` or `currentColor` change. With `useCallback` in place, the props `id` and `onClick` may change without rerendering the children (according to the above visible code at least), all other rerenders of `ColorButton` will lead to its children rerendering. Again, the child `ToggleButton` is lightweight and `id` or `onClick` are not likely to change more often than any other prop so the use of `useCallback` seems redundant here as well.

### Case 3: `ToggleButton`

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        /* code that uses isToggled, data, id and setButtonStyle */
    }, [isToggled, data, id, ...Object.values(dependencies)])
```

This case is elaborate with a lot of dependencies but from what I see, one way or the other, most of the component props will lead to a "new version" of `handleClick` and with the children being lightweight components, the argument to use `useCallback` seems weak.

## So when should I use `useCallback`?

As the docs say, use it in the very specific cases when you need a function to have referential equality between renders ...

- You have a component with a subset of children that are expensive to rerender and that should rerender much less often than the parent component but rerender due to a function prop changing identity whenever the parent rerenders. To me, this use case also signals bad design and I would attempt to divide the parent component into smaller components but what do I know, maybe this is not always possible.
- You have a function in the body of the functional component which is used in another hook (listed as a dependency) which is triggered every time due to the function changing identity whenever the component rerenders. Typically, you can omit such a function from the dependency array by [ignoring the lint rule](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880) even if this is not by the book. Other suggestions are to place such a function outside the body of the component or inside the hook that uses it, but there might be scenarios where none of this works out as intended.

Good to know connected to this is ...

- A function living outside a functional component will always have referential equality between renders.
- The setters returned by `useState` will always have referential equality between renders.

I said in the comments that you can use `useCallback` when there is function doing expensive calculations in a component that rerenders often but I was a bit off there. Let's say you have a function that does heavy calculations based on some prop that changes less often than a component rerenders. Then you *COULD* use `useCallback` and run a function inside it that returns a function with a closure with some computed value

```
const fn = useCallback(
    (
        () => {
            const a = ... // heavy calculation based on prop c
            const b = ... // heavy calculation based on prop c
            return () => { console.log(a + b) }
        }
    )()
, [c])
...
/* fn is used for something, either as a prop OR for something else */
```

This would effectively avoid calculating `a` and `b` every time the component rerenders without `c` changing, but the more straightforward way to do this would be to instead

```
const a = useMemo(() => /* calculate and return a */, [c])
const b = useMemo(() => /* calculate and return b */, [c])
const fn = () => console.log(a + b)
```

so here the use of `useCallback` just complicates things in a bad way.

## Conclusion

It's good to understand more complicated concepts in programming and to be able to use them, but part of the virtue is also to know **when** to use them. Adding code, and especially code that involves complicated concepts, comes at the price of reduced readability and code that is harder to debug with a lot of different mechanisms that interplay. Therefore, make sure you understand the hooks, but always try to not use them if you can. Especially `useCallback`, `useMemo` and `React.memo` (not a hook but a similar optimization) should, in my opinion, only be introduced when they are absolutely needed. `useRef` has its very own use cases but should also not be introduced when you can solve your problem without it.

---

Good work on the sandbox! Always makes it easier to reason about code. I took the liberty of forking your sandbox and refactoring it a bit: [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-picker-3o4v6). You can study the changes yourself if you want. Here is a summary:

- It's good that you know and use `useRef` and `useCallback` but I was able to remove all the uses, making the code much easier to understand (not only by removing these uses but by also removing the contexts where they are used).
- Try to work *with* React to simplify things. I know this is not a hands-on suggestion but the more you get into React, the more you will realize that you can do things co-operating with React, or you can do things your own way. Both will work but the latter will result in more headache for you and everybody else.
- Try to isolate the scope of a component; only delegate data that is necessary to child components and constantly question where you keep your state. Earlier you had click handlers in all three components and the flow was so complicated I didn't even bother to fully understand it. In my version, there is just one click handler in `ColorPicker` that is being delegated down. The buttons don't have to know what happens when you click them as long as the click handler takes care of that. Closures and the ability to pass functions as arguments are strong advantages of React and Javascript.
- Keys are important in React and it's good to see that you use them. Typically, the key should correspond to something that uniquely identifies a specific item. Good to use here would be `${r}_${g}_${b}` but then we would only be able to have one sample of each color in the button array. This is a natural limitation but if we don't want it, the only way to assign keys is to assign a unique identifier, which you did. I prefer using `Date.now()` but some would probably advise against it for some reason. You could use a global variable outside the functional component too if you don't want to use a ref.
- Try to do things the functional (immutable) way, and not the "old" Javascript way. For example, when adding to an array, use `[...oldArray, newValue]` and when assigning to an object, use `{...oldObject, newKey: newValue }`.

There are more things to say but I think it's better for you to study the refactored version and you can let me know if you wonder about anything.

Comment: if you try use context to share dependency ?

Comment: wow man thanks a lot I will definitely study this asap, I never had a chance to get my code reviewed ! –

Comment: sorry for the late reply I did study your sandbox last month but I found no time to answer, I wanted to ask you : 

I my original sandbox I had a component called ColorButton and another called ToggleButton, I did that because I share ToggleButton with all my components, since you removed it in your sandbox... is that a bad thing to do or did I do it wrong ?

Comment: If you have the exact same code in multiple components, then you should break it out into its own component if there is not a very particular reason not to do it. Just make sure to not make it overly complicated, as was the tendency with `ToggleButton` and `ColorButton`. 

Also, if two use cases are VERY similar, then maybe you can use the same component for both but add functionality that is triggered by some prop only set in one use case but not the other.